# Does EnhanceIO supports TRIM on SSD?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, ssd, cache

Does EnhanceIO supports TRIM on SSD? Or it has own implementation of similar technology?

Comment: have you googled to try to find this information?  Have you even gone to the source site to contact the vendor/author concerning this?

Comment: TRIM is something the operating system supports.  EnhanceIO is a SSD caching technique for Linux.  TRIM and EnhanceIO barely overlap.